# Safe to use -webkit-overflow-scrolling?

Tags: html, css, iframe, safari, webkit

I have an iframe that does not have scrollbars even if I put like overflow-y on when using safari for the ipad(latest version).

I seen many solutions saying to use `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` which does solve my problem but then I found [this website saying it is not a standard feature and to avoid using.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling)

So should I or should I not be using it? If not what should I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to use it - it's technically invalid, but it's required to get kinetic scrolling on iOS....kind of a pain that it gets flagged.

Answer (score 0):

You should be ok as long as you have an alternative for browsers that don't support it.

Comment: Where can I find what the alternatives for each browser are?

Comment: It shouldn't really matter, but there are plugins like iScroll, that were used before -webkit-overflow-scrolling which should be more compatible.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* need the use of a vendor-specific property, sure, but make sure your user interface does not rely on it and can operate perfectly if it wasn’t to work.

My suggestion is to try to work without/around vendor-specific properties at all costs since they are a grey zone in CSS. Plus, make sure to include other prefixes other than WebKit as well.

Comment: I tried all the ways I could think of without that tag but nothing worked. Unless you have any suggestions(I tried putting container around the iframe and setting height, and overflow-y:scroll, tried to just use overflow-y on iframe)